# how is output(echo) array without use of json_encode?(codeigniter)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

for output array Instead of using json_encode, use of what.(how is output(echo) array without use of json_encode?)
i use of codeigniter.

CI_Controller:

```
function auto_complete(){
    $hotel_search = $this->input->post('search_hotel');      
    echo json_encode($this->model_tour->auto_complete($hotel_search)); 
// if use of json_encode output is '[{"name":"salal"},{"name":"salaso"},{"name":"salasi"},{"name":"salsh"}]' if don want use of json_encode output is "Array"
}
```

CI_model:

```
function auto_complete($hotel_search)
    {

            $query_hotel_search = $this->db->order_by("id", "desc")->like('name', $hotel_search)->get('hotel_submits');
            if($query_hotel_search->num_rows()==0){
                return '0';
            }else{
                $data = array();
                foreach ($query_hotel_search->result() as $row)
                {
                   $data[] = array('name' => $row->name);
                }
                return $data;          
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to view the array, `print_r($array)` or `var_dump($array)` will work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it really helps show the structure of the array/JSON:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

It will show the $array broken out and will keep the tabbing so you can see how it's nested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the contents of the array, use `print_r` or `vardump`

If you want to do something useful with the information, you're going to have to loop through the array

```
foreach($this->model_tour->auto_complete($hotel_search) as $key => $value){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: i sent contents to AJAX CALL, did in AJAX CALL must set dataype: json, what do i do?

Comment: If your ajax call is expecting json, then you'll have to provide json. Don't put diesel into a gas-burning car...

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . ' = ' . $value . "\n";
}
```

That will give you the array as string.

You can also use print_r()

```
print_r($array);
```

or var_dump()

```
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: i want sent contents to AJAX CALL, did in AJAX CALL must set dataype: json, what do i do?

Comment: I guess you are using jQuery? If the data-type in the ajax-call is set to JSON you have to add output headers in php to tell the ajax-response that the information you print is acctual json-data. And if you need to send json back to the ajax-call you are supposed to use json_encode()

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options at your disposal:

- `json_encode` (which you mention yourself)
- `print_r` or `var_dump` (timw4mail mentions this)
- `implode` (however, this won't work for nested arrays, and it will only display the keys)
- a combination of `array_map` (to format individual array elements using your own function) and `implode` (to combine the results)
- write your own recursive function that flattens an array into a string

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, any .ajax(), .get(), or .post() function will try to guess the data type being returned from the HTTP request. Set the content type of your controller to JSON:

```
$hotel_search = $this->input->post('search_hotel');
$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output( json_encode($this->model_tour->auto_complete($hotel_search)) );
```